# How to set background drawable of ListView selected row?

Tags: android

When clicked to an item of ListView, I am saving the position of clicked item. Then in `getView()`, there is an if statement which compares the current row position with saved position and changing background. However it is not drawing the image. Here is my getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (position == selectedPosition)
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_bg);
        else
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_bg);

        return row;

}
```

I don't want to highlight current selection row. I want to draw a bitmap on it permanently. When another row selected, I want to draw bitmap on it and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Instead of trying to change background image of row, I am putting an ImageView to the row. In `onItemClick()` I am saving the position of selected row. Finally in `getView()` method I am setting visibility of row as `VISIBLE` or `GONE` according to position of current row.